# ACF fields are not rendering in the WordPress frontend page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I was trying to create 2 custom Guttenberg blocks out of those the header block is rendering but the ACF field values which I am posting from the page backend are not showing in the frontend I could see the  and

tags but not the values.

Here is my code to register and render the blocks in functions.php

```
// Register and enqueue scripts and styles for the blocks
function custom_gutenberg_blocks_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'header-block-editor',
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'blocks/header-block.js',
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-editor'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'feed-block-editor',
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'blocks/feed-block.js',
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-editor'),
        '1.0',
        true
    );
}
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'custom_gutenberg_blocks_scripts');

// Register the header block
function register_header_block() {
    register_block_type(
        'custom-gutenberg-blocks/header-block',
        array(
            'editor_script'   => 'header-block-editor',
            'render_callback' => 'render_header_block',
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'register_header_block');

// Render callback function for the header block
function render_header_block($attributes) {
    $heading = get_field('main_heading');
    $subheading = get_field('sub_heading');
    
    // Rendering the header block's HTML
    echo '<div class="header-block">';
    echo '<h1>' . esc_html($heading) . '</h1>';
    echo '<p>' . esc_html($subheading) . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Also the following is my header-block.js

```
(function(blocks, editor, components, i18n) {
  var el = wp.element.createElement;
  var registerBlockType = blocks.registerBlockType;
  var TextControl = components.TextControl;

  registerBlockType('custom-gutenberg-blocks/header-block', {
    title: i18n.__('Header Block', 'custom-gutenberg-blocks'),
    description: i18n.__('Custom header block with ACF fields.', 'custom-gutenberg-blocks'),
    category: 'common',
    icon: 'heading',
    attributes: {
      headingText: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'text',
        selector: 'h1',
      },
      subheadingText: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'text',
        selector: 'p',
      },
    },
    edit: function(props) {
      var attributes = props.attributes;

      function updateHeadingText(newText) {
        props.setAttributes({ headingText: newText });
      }

      function updateSubheadingText(newText) {
        props.setAttributes({ subheadingText: newText });
      }

      return [
        el('div', { className: props.className },
          el('h1', {}, attributes.headingText),
          el(TextControl, {
            label: i18n.__('Heading Text', 'custom-gutenberg-blocks'),
            value: attributes.headingText,
            onChange: updateHeadingText,
          }),
          el('p', {}, attributes.subheadingText),
          el(TextControl, {
            label: i18n.__('Subheading Text', 'custom-gutenberg-blocks'),
            value: attributes.subheadingText,
            onChange: updateSubheadingText,
          })
        )
      ];
    },
    save: function(props) {
      var attributes = props.attributes;

      return el('div', { className: props.className },
        el('h1', {}, attributes.headingText),
        el('p', {}, attributes.subheadingText)
      );
    },
  });
})(
  window.wp.blocks,
  window.wp.editor,
  window.wp.components,
  window.wp.i18n
);
```

What I am posting from the page is

[image]

What I am getting in the frontend is

[image]